# Create dynamic proxy for existing Serializable object with no available constructor

Tags: java, java-11, java-bytecode-asm, byte-buddy, cglib

I have an instance of an object for which I need to create proxy to intercept one of the methods:

- The object implements an interface, but I need to proxy the full type not just implement the interface.
- I don't know the exact type of the object, only its interface class.
- There are no accessible public constructors.
- The object is Serializable.
- I have full accessibility to read the library code, but no ability to change any of it.

So what I need to do is something like:

```
 TheObject obj = library.getObject();
 TheObject proxy = createProxyObject(obj);
 library.doSomethingWith(proxy);
```

It seems to me that theoretically this should be possible as the object is Serializable, but I can't find any way of using that.

Note on the following: I've been trying using cglib but I'm not tied to that at all. If it is possible in asm, javaassist, or any other library that would be fine.

What I have so far with cglib is I can proxy a simple object with a public constructor:

```
public class SimpleObject {
  private String name;
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  // return a random number
  public int getRandom() {
    return (int)(Math.random() * 100);
  }
}

public void testCglibEnhancer() throws Exception {
  SimpleObject object = new SimpleObject();
  object.setName("object 1");
  System.out.println(object.getName() + " -> " + object.getRandom());

  Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
  enhancer.setSuperclass(object.getClass());

  // intercept getRandom and always return 32
  ProxyRefDispatcher passthrough = proxy -> object;
  MethodInterceptor fixedRandom = (obj, method, args, proxy) -> 32;
  enhancer.setCallbacks(new Callback[]{passthrough, fixedRandom});
  enhancer.setCallbackFilter(method -> method.getName().equals("getRandom") ? 1 : 0);

  SimpleObject proxy = (SimpleObject)enhancer.create();
  System.out.println(proxy.getName() + " -> " + proxy.getRandom()); // always 32
}
```

But I've been unable to replicate this using an object with no public constructor:

```
public static class ComplexObject implements Serializable {
  public static ComplexObject create() {
    return new ComplexObject();
  }
  private String name;
  private ComplexObject() {
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public int getRandom() {
    return (int)(Math.random() * 100);
  }
}

ComplexObject proxy = (ComplexObject)enhancer.create();
// throws IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors
```

As the object is Serializable, I can clone it:

```
public static <T extends Serializable> T cloneViaSerialization(T source) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
  out.writeObject(source);

  ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
  ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
  return (T)in.readObject();
}

public void testClone() throws Exception {
  ComplexObject object1 = ComplexObject.create();
  object1.setName("object 1");

  ComplexObject object2 = cloneViaSerialization(object1);
  object2.setName("object 2");

  System.out.println(object1.getName() + " -> " + object1.getRandom());
  System.out.println(object2.getName() + " -> " + object2.getRandom());
}
```

So is there any way I can get cglib (or any library) to use this approach?

```
ComplexObject object = library.getObject();
ObjectInputStream in = ... // serialised version of object

Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
enhancer.setSuperclass(object.getClass());
// add callbacks etc.

// note createFromSerialized is not a existing method of
// Enhancer - it is what I'm trying to synthesise somehow
ComplexObject proxy = (ComplexObject)enhancer.createFromSerialized(in);
```

Thanks

Comment: If the object already exists and is serializable why do you need a constructor for it?

Comment: @user207421 I don't need the constructor - cglib Enhancer does to create a proxy, or it throws `IllegalArgumentException: No visible constructors`. That's where I got stuck - how to get the Enhancer to create a proxy without a constructor.

Comment: Well same question, why does it need one? Not that you probably know the answer. There is a persistent myth that Serializable objects need a default constructor, but that's a misreading. Take it up with the cglib guys. If they come back with the myth, ask them where in the Java Object Serialization Specification it says so. It doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working:

1. Created a derived class definition using ASM.
2. Added this class definition to the same class loader as the target
   class.
3. Serialised the existing object to a byte array.
4. Injected the derived class name into the serialised byte array.
5. Deserialised the resulting bytes using standard
   ObjectInputStream.readObject.

For (1), I couldn't get cglib or byte-buddy to create the class I needed, so I switched to ASM.

For (2), I used a custom class loader to load the whole jar file containing the target class.

This does mean I end up with a clone of the original object not a proxy as per the question, but that works fine for what I need.

**For the serialisation hack:**

I created a few example minimal classes, serialized them to disk and compared the resulting binary data.

To inject the class name:

1. Serialised the full parent object to a byte array.
2. Manually created a byte array for the derived class header (see below).

Both byte arrays contain the stream header data (magic, version and initial object type), so I took that from (2) for simplicity, although I did have to tweak a couple of bytes.

So then just created a stream of all of (2) followed by all of (1) except the first 6 bytes.

To create the byte array for the derived class, I just looked at the delivered Java source and came up with the following:

```
/*
 * Returned array contains:
 * - stream header
 * - class header
 * - end block / class desc markers for next class
 */
private byte[] derivedClass(Class<?> clss) throws IOException {
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);

  ObjectStreamClass osc = ObjectStreamClass.lookup(clss);
  oos.writeUTF(osc.getName());
  oos.writeLong(osc.getSerialVersionUID());
  oos.write(SC_SERIALIZABLE);      // flags
  oos.writeShort(0);               // field count
  oos.writeByte(TC_ENDBLOCKDATA);
  oos.writeByte(TC_CLASSDESC);
  oos.flush();

  // header appears to write 0x77 (TC_BLOCKDATA) and 0x54 (???) for bytes 5 & 6
  // samples streamed from other files use 0x73 (TC_OBJECT) and 0x72 (TC_CLASSDESC)
  byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
  bytes[4] = TC_OBJECT;
  bytes[5] = TC_CLASSDESC;

  return bytes;
}
```

Have not tested this as a general approach, but appears to work fine for my case.

Comment: That's actually impressive. And horrifying. Mind to elaborate (especially the 4th step)?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn sure - see above.